# which sentence is correct: "I am a student of X college", or "I am a student from X college"?

Tags: prepositions

> I am a student of X college.

or

> I am a student from X college.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual expression would be "I am a student *at* X College".

We usually use *a student of* when referring to the subject being studied.

You might use *a student from X College* when visiting another college, or on a work placement, for example (with the sense that X College has sent you there).